# scala reflection can not work at this case

Tags: java, scala, reflection

I declared a class:

```
trait TO {  
    @BeanProperty var id: String = _ 
    @BeanProperty var age : Int = _     
    @BeanProperty var createdAt : Long = _ 
    @BeanProperty var disable: Boolean = _ 
}
class UMTTestObject extends TO {
    @BeanProperty var inner: UMTInnerTO = _
}
class UMTInnerTO extends TO{}
```

And In reflection, this does not work for setAge of UMTInnerObject:

```
setter.invoke(inner, 0)
```

while setter is setAge of UMTInnerObject, inner is an instance of UMTInnerObject

The error msg shows:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: me.baihe.blackhole.luna.helpers.TO$class.setAge(Lme/baihe/blackhole/luna/helpers/TO;I)V

That is very puzzle--

Anyone knows why?

Comment: It seems you are dealing with the Java Reflection API. I encourage you to read the Scala Reflection Documentation, in particular this [section](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html#accessing_and_invoking_members_of_runtime_types), in order to learn how to set a value for `inner` with the Scala Reflection API instead.

Comment: Can you provide some more details? For example, how do you obtain `setter`?

Comment: @ Jesús López-González, so you think the scala can not use java reflection api, because of the compatibility？

Comment: @user1453345 Scala can use java reflection as well, but it's obviously more limited because it doesn't support many Scala concepts. I agree it's complex, but once you learn the fundamentals you find out that it's not rocket science. By the way, as @ghik mentioned, it would be nice if you explain where the `setter` comes from, in order to help you with the Java Reflection API.

Comment: @ Jesús López-González, get the setter in Java way. classOf[UMTInnerTO].getMethod("setAge", classOf[Int]). I debug it , and set the breakpoint here, it shows the setter is just the setAge method from the inner, but it fails to invoke on the inner object:(

Answer (score 2):

This REPL session shows how you can invoke the setter with the Scala Reflection API:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime. { universe => ru }
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe=>ru}

scala> trait TO { var age: Int = _ }
defined trait TO

scala> class UMTInnerTO extends TO
defined class UMTInnerTO

scala> val inner = new UMTInnerTO
inner: UMTInnerTO = UMTInnerTO@173379f

scala> val m = ru.runtimeMirror(inner.getClass.getClassLoader)
m: reflect.runtime.universe.Mirror ...

scala> val im = m.reflect(inner)
im: reflect.runtime.universe.InstanceMirror = instance mirror for UMTInnerTO@173379f

scala> val setterSymb = (ru.typeOf[UMTInnerTO].members find (_.name.decoded == "age_=")).get
setterSymb: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = method age_=

scala> val setter = im.reflectMethod(setterSymb.asMethod)
setter: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodMirror = method mirror for TO.age_$eq(x$1: scala.Int): scala.Unit (bound to UMTInnerTO@173379f)

scala> inner.age
res0: Int = 0

scala> setter(5)
res1: Any = ()

scala> inner.age
res2: Int = 5
```

You may visit the [Scala Reflection Documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) to understand what is happening in the snippet.

--

**UPDATED**: Anyway, if you are still interested in the Java API, here we go!

You should be aware of *setters* in Scala don't use the Java naming convention. You won't find a `setAge` method (at least, if you don't declare it manually). Instead you have to search for an `age_=` method.

```
scala> classOf[UMTInnerTO].getMethod("age_$eq", classOf[Int])
res0: java.lang.reflect.Method = public void UMTInnerTO.age_$eq(int)

scala> inner.age
res1: Int = 0

scala> res0.invoke(inner, 3: Integer)
res2: Object = null

scala> inner.age
res3: Int = 3
```

This [post](http://dustinmartin.net/getters-and-setters-in-scala/) on getters and setters could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I have read the scala reflection api before:) And I thought the scala api is a little complex. I just want to get the setter, and getter method to call a normal class

Comment: But I add the @BeanProperty for each field. And I did get the setter of setAge

Comment: I found this probleam is not so obvious, becuase if I execute the codes in REPL, it works. So I think it maybe a hidden bug in scala. I will dig further

Comment: Sorry, I thought that the annotation was irrelevant. Absolutely, you are right, the `setAge` exists. Anyway, my reduced example is working fine to me (both in REPL and Scala-IDE with 2.10.1). I recommend you to edit your question and go further in the sentence "while setter is setAge of UMTInnerObject, inner is an instance of UMTInnerObject". What are exactly `inner` and `UMTInnerObject`? Besides, you may explain that it works in the REPL and tell us about your current environment.